# want to filter out Windows admin shares from my arrangedObjects NSArrayController

Tags: cocoa, binding, nsarraycontroller

I have everything set up in my NSArrayController to have my files owner representedObject be the data source for a tableview that I have.

Within my bindings in interface builder I would like to use the filter predicate to filter out any items in the arraycontroller that have a $ in the name.... specifically ending in $ actually as this is how windows admin shares look like when I get the array of FTP shares I am collecting.

I have set up the filter predicate as so:
controller key: selection
modelKeyPath : directorsAndFiles

value Transformer: hmm I dont know? can you help

wanted:
eliminate any items that have $ characters in them

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need a value transformer in this case. A value transformer changes the display of a value. For example, it may cause the number 2 to be displayed as "€ 2,00" -- or whatever you may like.

Second, the predicate syntax you're looking for is "ENDSWITH" as in :

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name not ENDSWITH '$'"];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you "set up" the filter predicate, what you're doing is binding it--you need to set the key path to a valid property of the whatever object you set as the controller key. So, instead, you should set the controller key to some controller object, and the key path to some property, perhaps named something like `windowsPredicate`.

Then, in whatever object you've bound to, add a windowsPredicate property which returns an `NSPredicate`. You'll create the `NSPredicate` yourself, using something like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name not like '*$'"];
```

(The * means "anything", so that roughly translates to "don't end with $".) Check the `NSPredicate` documentation for more info. Good luck!

Comment: I get an error when I use that string(slightly modified):  Unable to parse the format string "title NOT like '*$'"

Comment: I added a NSPredicate *windowsPredicate: method to my controller then hooked it up in the interface builder as:  bind to files owner  keypath:self.windowsPredicate  and thats when i get that error.

Comment: Check http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/ for exact details, but my guess is that either the single quotes or the $ is not working. Try "title not like \"*$\"".